# How to control a scanner via an iPad?

Tags: ipad, scanning

i've an HP AirPrint enabled scanner / printer. I would like to scan something and then send it to an eMail. This, only using an iPad. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HP doesn't make any iOS apps with this functionality, no - have you tried opening the printer's webpage in Safari on the iPad however?

None of my OfficeJet 6500 or 4500 printers can run the scan functions from their status pages, but perhaps your model is slightly different.